# Wrong colors when rendering on AMD Radeon

Tags: graphics-card, colors, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce, opengl

I decided to run my engine on a friend's computer, but I ran into some problems. For some reason, the wrong colors, the colors of the scene have become terribly cold. What could be the reason? Hardware feature?

I tested on the Nvidia GeForce 920mx, and everything was perfectly displayed.
He has an AMD Radeon, Debian GNU / Linux Stretch. I have the same system.

Engine written using OpenGL
[image]
[image]

And how it should be:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Both screens profiled properly? [Most aren't even close]. Correct profile being used at runtime? [I know nothing about coding or OpenGL, but I'm not bad at colour-proofing;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin, I guess so, since the rest of the content is displayed correctly.

Comment: Test with a broad gamut regular sRGB photograph on both machines, just to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such possibility at the moment, but when calling `glxgears`, the colors were displayed equally on both screens